# Remove records matching a value on a single column occurring within a 5 minute window of a different value on the same column

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
require(data.table)
require(tidyverse)

df <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(123, "2018-01-05 09:09:02", "Mobile",
                         123, "2018-01-06 11:11:15", "Organic",
                         123, "2018-01-07 13:24:45", "Email",
                         123, "2018-01-07 13:24:55", "Organic",
                         321, "2018-01-05 15:15:29", "Organic",
                         989, "2018-01-08 08:09:21", "Feeds",
                         989, "2018-01-08 08:09:55", "Organic",
                         989, "2018-01-10 10:21:40", "Email"), nrow = 8,
                       ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(NULL, c("customer_id", "entry_time",
                                                                       "channel"))))

df$entry_time <- as.POSIXct(df$entry_time)


 df
 customer_id          entry_time channel
1         123 2018-01-05 09:09:02  Mobile
2         123 2018-01-06 11:11:15 Organic
3         123 2018-01-07 13:24:45   Email
4         123 2018-01-07 13:24:55 Organic
5         321 2018-01-05 15:15:29 Organic
6         989 2018-01-08 08:09:21   Feeds
7         989 2018-01-08 08:09:55 Organic
8         989 2018-01-10 10:21:40   Email
```

What I would like to do is remove all "organic" records occurring within a five minute window of a non-organic record, for each customer.

In other words, I want to remove all records where: 1) channel = organic and 2) entry_time < 5 minutes removed from the previous record and 3) the previous record's channel != Organic. I need to be able to do this for each customer id.

My desired output looks as follows:

```
df_desired <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(123, "2018-01-05 09:09:02", "Mobile",
                         123, "2018-01-06 11:11:15", "Organic",
                         123, "2018-01-07 13:24:45", "Email",
                         321, "2018-01-05 15:15:29", "Organic",
                         989, "2018-01-08 08:09:21", "Feeds",
                         989, "2018-01-10 10:21:40", "Email"), nrow = 6,
                       ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(NULL, c("customer_id", "entry_time",
                                                                       "channel"))))

df_desired$entry_time <- as.POSIXct(df_desired$entry_time)

df_desired
customer_id          entry_time channel
1         123 2018-01-05 09:09:02  Mobile
2         123 2018-01-06 11:11:15 Organic
3         123 2018-01-07 13:24:45   Email
4         321 2018-01-05 15:15:29 Organic
5         989 2018-01-08 08:09:21   Feeds
6         989 2018-01-10 10:21:40   Email
```

I am able to do this with the following nested loop (apologies for exposing you to this monstrosity).

```
dat_splt <- split(df, df$customer_id)


for (h in 1:length(dat_splt)){
dat_splt[[h]]$prox_flag <- 0
if (nrow(dat_splt[[h]]) == 1)
{next}
else
{for (g in 2:nrow(dat_splt[[h]])){
if (dat_splt[[h]][g,]$channel != "Organic")
{next}
else if (dat_splt[[h]][g-1,]$channel != "Organic" &
         as.numeric((difftime(dat_splt[[h]][g,]$entry_time, dat_splt[[h]][g-1,]$entry_time, units = "mins")) < 5))
{dat_splt[[h]][g,]$prox_flag <- 1}
else
{next}
}}
}

dat <- rbindlist(dat_splt)

dat <- dat %>%
   filter(prox_flag != 1)
```

Needless to say, this does not scale well. Can someone please help me unravel this Gordian knot of a solution into something more practical?

Much thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beauty of R is that almost all operations are vectorized, so you can compare multiple things at the same time, and you don't need for loops.

In this case you have to compare all values with the one directly before, which can be done by comparing `df[-1,]` with `df[-nrow(df),]`, i.e. the second row gets compared to the first, the third with the second, and so on.
Only the first row is an exception: it always needs to stay.

Also, I don't think there's a real need to split by customer, or can they be interleaved? If not, it's enough to look if the customer_id is different from the row above. The code that does it in one run:

```
nr <- nrow(df)
df_desired <- rbind(
    df[1,],
    df[-1,][!(df$customer_id[-1]==df$customer_id[-nr] &
              df$channel[-1]=='Organic' &
              df$channel[-nr]!='Organic' &
              as.numeric(df$entry_time[-1]-df$entry_time[-nr],
                   units='mins')<5)
            ,])
```

And a final remark: I don't know where you got your data, but first storing as a matrix and then using `as.data.frame` is generally not the best idea. The `c` you use to give your data to the matrix means everything is coerced to the same class, meaning all numerics change into character. While a data.frame can handle different classes fine.
In this case, you're just using 'id' as an identifier, but if you have columns that you want to be numeric, you need to convert them back, like you did with the POSIXct.

Comment: Thank you. This is extremely helpful!